# Анимация ломаной линии на сайте

Tags: html5, svg

Как сделать эффект линии, которая при загрузке сайта плавно сверху идёт к центру, там подобным образом изгибается и спускается дальше? Мне подсказали, что можно использовать SVG, а как именно? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое, это изучить и использовать какую-либо библиотеку для работы с SVG, например d3.js, [сайт библиотеки](https://d3js.org/), [разбор примера](https://habrahabr.ru/post/207908/) svg анимации на Хабре с использованием, этой библиотеки.